# Launch local pdf file with external pdf viewer using react-native and expo

Tags: android, react-native, android-intent, expo

I'm new to react-native. I have a sample pdf file on my mobile storage and tried to launch in an external pdf viewer using **IntentLauncher.startActivityAsync**. It launches the external app but doesn't open the file. Here is my code,

```
      IntentLauncher.startActivityAsync("android.intent.action.VIEW", {
        data: FileUri, 
        flags: 1,
        type: "application/pdf",
      });
```

This is my **file-url: '/storage/emulated/0/MyFolder/sample-file.pdf'**.

I think the data (key) may be wrong. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any other way, now I am using React Native CLI to overcome the issue.

[react-native-file-viewer](https://github.com/vinzscam/react-native-file-viewer#open-a-local-file) fulfilled my need. And here is my code,

```
  const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
  );
  if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
    FileViewer.open(path, {showOpenWithDialog: true})
      .then(() => {
        // something useful here
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('err: ', err);
      });
  } else {
    console.log('Permission denied');
  }
```

And this is my **path: 'file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/test.pdf'**